# Changing Directory Names in Python

Tags: python, directory, date

I'm trying to change how my directories and files within them are all labelled. Currently the system is "082411-SomeNameHere" (mmddyy-Title) and I'd like to change it to "110824-SomeNameHere".

I know the moving of the numbers is fairly simple, but I'm mostly unsure on how to access the names in the directories and change all them.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os, re, shutil

r = re.compile(r'^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})-(.*)$')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/topdir'):
    for filename in files:
        match = r.match(filename)
        if match:
            newfilename = match.group(3) + match.group(1) + match.group(2) + '-' + match.group(4)
            newfilename = os.path.join(root, newfilename)
            oldfilename = os.path.join(root, filename)

            # Rename oldfilename to newfilename
            shutil.move(oldfilename, newfilename)
```

Basically this traverses the directory structure using `os.walk`, looks for files that appear to have the old naming convention, extracts the parts out, and does a rename with `shutil.move`.

Comment: I went with this one only because I understood it better. Adam's code may have been faster - but made a little less sense to me. I did steal the "os.walk(os.curdir)" from Adam's code though.


This was a huge help thank you! One small issue though - this changed the contents of all the folders like it's supposed to, but not the parent directory folder names.

eg: I have folder 061411-Name and then inside it's changed to 110614-FileA.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) for the directory and file traversal.
And you can use [`shutil.move`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) for the file renaming.

```
import os
import shutil
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for filename in files:
        shutil.move( # alternative: `os.rename`
                os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                os.path.join(dirpath, filename_with_changes),
            )
```

"...the moving of the numbers is fairly simple" so I leave that to you :D
Welcome to StackOverflow.